Uncaught Error: Cannot wrap function in Figma
I am building a plugin for figma but getting this issue :7068-b259bcf26459713c.min.js.br:1071 Uncaught Error: Cannot wrap function
for now I am just building a functionality for select a image and after hitting upload it will console log the files data
but after passing the files data through post message I am getting that error
here are the code files
ui.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Figma Plugin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Image Uploader</h2>
  <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*" multiple>
  <button id="upload">Upload</button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('upload').onclick = () => {
      const input = document.getElementById('imageInput');
      console.log(input.files)
      const files = input.files;
      parent.postMessage({ pluginMessage: { type: 'upload-images', files } }, '*');
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>

code.ts
figma.showUI(__html__);

figma.ui.onmessage = async (msg) => {
    if (msg.type === 'upload-images') {
        const files = msg.files;
        // Handle the uploaded image files here
        console.log('Uploaded files:', files);
    }

    figma.closePlugin();
};

